# Running a Regression... Sign on Coefficient seems to be the "wrong way"

Tags: regression, interpretation

[image]

I am looking at county level data to assess which variables are correlated with poverty. The dependent variable is poverty. As you can see, I am running a linear regression and here are the results. I am confused as to why having a high percent of college students would have a positive relationship with poverty, given that the sign of the coefficient is positive. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+sign+wrong for the same question in various related contexts.

Answer (score 0):

#### Positive correlation

Correlations or regression coefficients may not need to be causal relationships. There are multiple reasons why you could observe a positive correlation while you would (theoretically) expect a negative relationship

- 'College' can correlate with other latent (non observed) variables (or variables that are wrongly implemented into the model, e.g maybe they should not be linear). For instance it might relate to a younger age or it might relate to large cities (both these variables can be causes for poverty).
- 'College' might correlate positively with other variables ([multicollinearity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity)) and end up with a negative coefficient (even from a causal perspective). Multiple factors together can relate to the same concept, like parents socio-economic status, IQ, etc. With this it can be that you have some [interaction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)) that is negative and this get's coded by the main effect.

  In your case, it can be that %high school and %college are very much correlated and relate both *positively* to the wealth of the region. But the *negative* coefficient for %college can relate to the ratio %college/%high school or difference %college-%high school.

  A related aspect is [Simpson's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

#### Positive causal effect

In addition it might be that you indeed have a positive correlation due to a causal effect. It is unclear what your poverty variable means. Is it the number of people with high debts, the average income, etc.. ?

For some definitions I would not be surprised that people with a college degree are more poor.

For instance, you could be looking at the percentage of people with a low income (college people might not have an income but live of their parents) or the percentage of people with no or negative wealth (people with a college degree have high debts, either from tuition or from investments). It is possible that you find more "poor" people among the college-group than among other groups. Thanks to the surgeons and lawyers the people with a college degree have a high average income, but those that do not have jobs are *very* poor. The variance is large.

Comment: The model includes a measure of income, so the college coefficient represents the “effect” of additional college or adv. degree graduates and fewer HS dropouts (compositionally), while holding per capita income and population constant (plus all the other variables). This is an odd counterfactual, since schooling has been linked to higher income in a causal way. But you could well imagine that counties with a large fraction of students and grads with degrees in basket weaving (or, more seriously, with jobs that have non-monetary perks), that are demographically younger, could have more poverty.

Comment: Particularly if poverty is defined in a relative way, rather than an absolute one. All this is to say that there is at least another interpretation. A test  here would be to drop income from the model to see if that flips the college sign.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov that would relate to the point where I speak about Simpson's paradox. College is negatively associated with poverty (more education is less poverty) but within subgroups, it might be negatively associated and so if you include other variables that encode for these subgroups (like income) then it might give this unexpected positive coefficient (college, when corrected, positively correlates with poverty)....

Comment: ...This would be indeed an odd relationship, and I suspect that removing income from the model is not changing the sign. Maybe there are some effects that college has a causal effect on poverty (like increasing debts), but I suspect that the more important explanation for the unexpected sign would be that we are looking at aggregated data. The people that are poor might not need to be the same people with a college education. This is what I suspect is the most likely reason behind the statistical correlation.

Answer (score 0):

First of, what does the "% college" variable in your dataset actually mean? Does it mean "the percent of people in this county who are CURRENTLY college students?" Or does it mean "the percent of people in this county who have a college degree (or any college experience)?" These are VERY different variables.

If it means "the % who are currently college students" then the positive relationship might not be surprising because even though graduating from college is associated with higher income college students themselves often have very low incomes - or no income at all!

But my guess is that the variable is actually measuring "% of people in the county who have a college degree." In that case you WOULD expect it to be negatively correlated with  poverty, except that your model is ALSO trying to control for "% high school" which I assume means "the percent of people in the county who ONLY have a high school degree (or any high school experience?)." This is a problem because theses two variables (%HS and % coll) almost certainly have very high multicollinearity, especially if these variables measure coll/HS "experience" rather than getting a degree. If (say) 30% of people in a county have some college experience then that already tells you a lot about how many people in that county only have high school experience (probably around 70%). When you have two variables that are that closely correlated in the same model you can get nonsensical results.

My advice:

step 1: Go back to the data and verify what the HS and Coll variables are actually measuring

step 2: Try running a version of the model that only controls for college, but not high school and see if the effect is in the expected direction